# sphinx documentation - excluding rst files that begin with a specific character?

Tags: python-sphinx

I work on page drafts in my sphinx doc that I don't want to be available when I run `sphinx-build`.

for example I have files named `_bob.md` , `_mistbuddy.md` etc.

in my conf.py file I put:

```
exclude_patterns = [ '**/_*']
```

to ignore these file.

This works on load - **files ignored** :

[image: TOC working]

**However**, if I then click on one of the topics, and **ALL** pages are available.
[image: Broken TOC]

I have tried `.. only:: <tag>` however, a directive doesn't work on all contents in a file.

Thank you.

Comment: When you run `make html`, Sphinx rebuilds only the changed files. Try `make clean html` to purge files that were previously built.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  That is a great point!  I will try that and see if it fixes.  I think I might have been overthinking.  I created a drafts folder and put all the files in there (at the same level of docs).  At some point I need to understand doing both draft and publish versions...but since I am still bumbling..that will probably be awhile.

Comment: I'm not sure if this really matters, but in the question title it says "excluding rst files", while your actual files seem to be Markdown files.

Comment: Thank you mzjn.  I said rst (even though they are md) to peel away the rtx -> Myst goop and focus on my challenge regardless of .rst or .md